# Какой метод лучше использовать?

Tags: c#

Задача проста - управлять службой звука. Когда надо включить\выключить. Всё.
Есть следующие 2 метода (найдены на просторах интернета по первому запросу:
1)

```
private void StartSoundService()
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(audioServiceName);
            if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                sc.Start();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(300000000));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private void StopSoundService()
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(audioServiceName);
            if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                sc.Stop();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan(300000000));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

2) Но я обнаружил, что в приложение с формами сразу можно добавить элемент ServiceController, которому можно указать службу за которой надо следить. Через её переменную так же останавливать и запускать службу.

Что лучше использовать 1 или 2 вариант?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Первый метод у вас запускает службу, второй - останавливает. Что значит какой лучше использовать?

Comment: Первый способ может запускать и останавливать службу, второй это тоже может делать, и я вот спрашиваю каким лучше пользоваться? Т.е. выбираю самый надёжный из двух, в которым вероятность что что-то пойдёт не так минимальная.

Comment: Просто есть подозрение, что вы описываете один и тот же подход (через ServiceController), попробуйте оба, накидайте код. Посмотрите чем они отличаются.

Comment: Похоже вы правы, это одно и тоже, просто через элементы его можно объявить более компактнее.